# CSS Transform Matrix to pixel

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am using CSS transform matrix as `transform: matrix(1.15782, 0, 0, 1.15782, -82.5232, -137.397);` for zooming and moving an element. I would like to get actual no of pixels the element got translated.

If I use

```
`const style = getComputedStyle(element);
  const matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
  return {left: matrix.m41, top: matrix.m42};`
```

I get values as `{left: -82.5232, top: -137.397}` but I would like to convert this to get actual px values.

Is it possible or is there any other way to get left and top of the element. I have tried `offsetTop & offsetLeft`, but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `matrix.m42 / element.offsetTop` to top and `matrix.m41 / element.offsetLeft` to left

```js
var element=document.getElementsByClassName("changed")[0];
const style = getComputedStyle(element);
const matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);

var leftElem = matrix.m41 / element.offsetLeft;
var topElem = matrix.m42 / element.offsetTop;
console.log(leftElem +'px , top:' +topElem + 'px');
```

```css
.changed {
  transform: matrix(1, 2, -1, 1, 80, 80);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="changed">Changed</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just need to use `scale` and `translate` property to get actual pxs as below.

```
const style = getComputedStyle(element);
const matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
const scale = matrix.m11;
return {left: matrix.m41*scale, top: matrix.m42*scale};
```